# change script rename from generate A0 A1 A2 A3 to A001 A002 A003

Tags: linux, shell, rename

How to rename the file from A0 A1 A2 A3 to A001 A002 A003
I have a rename code like this:

```
n=$(ls -1 | grep '^A' -c)             # find the number for A files
nfiles=$(ls -1 *.obj| grep -v '^A');  # list of all non-A files
for file in $nfiles;                  # for each of the non-A files
do
n=$(($n+1));
new_file=A$n.obj                   # new name with next available A file name
mv $file $new_file                 # rename with new file name
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some changes:

```
n=$(ls [A]* | wc -l)
nfiles=$(ls [^A]*.obj)               # list of all non-A files
for file in $nfiles;                 # for each of the non-A files
do
  n=$(($n+1));
  new_file=$(printf "A%03d.obj" $n)  # new name with next available A file name
  echo mv $file $new_file            # rename with new file name
done
```

Comment: I got it. Thx you too much

Answer (score 0):

How about if the original file is another name eg. ant.obj dog.obj , how to change the code to rename into A001 A002 A003 ....

Comment: This is a different question; try something first, then ask it... And Perreal's answer should nearly work also.